# Automatically fix sonar rule

Tags: bash, sonarqube

I'm looking for automaticaly fix this rule :

```
checkstyle:javadoc.SummaryJavadocCheck
```

I have over 1000 javadoc that don't have point at the end of the first line. I don't want to edit file one by one but perhaps in bash i can do a replace of the first line after  /** that don't have point at the end?

Can someone help me for this or another idea?

## EDIT1:

Invalid javadoc :

```
/**
 * Javadoc comment
 *
 * @return object an object
 */
```

Correct javadoc

```
/**
 * Javadoc comment.
 *
 * @return object an object
 */
```

Sonar want a point at the end of the line. It's not critical, just want to know if it's possible.

thanks

Comment: I don't know javadoc, but my guess is that you mean you want a `.` at the end of all lines following a line containing `/**`, right ?

Comment: yes but if the line has more than 100 characters, the line is automatically wrap to new line, so possibly, the `.` is not just at the end of the following line containing `/**`but it represent 90% and i can do all the other line manually ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `awk` or `sed`, or pure `bash` : match exactly `/**` then add a dot on next line when that line does not have one. `sed` and `bash` versions below :

**sed version:**

```sh
sed -i.bak '/^\/\*\*$/{n;s/\([^\.]\)$/\1./;}' file1 file2 ...
```

Explanation :

`-i.bak` edit files inline, and create a backup (.bak).

`/^\/\*\*$/` matches only lines which contain exactly `/**`.

`{...}` sed command block

`n` append next line in pattern space.

`s/\([^\.]\)$/\1./` replace non "`.`" (`\([^\.]\)$`) last character with itself and a dot (`\1.`).

**Pure bash solution:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^/\*\*$ ]]; then
        read -r line2
        [[ $line2 =~ \.$ ]] || line2="$line2."
        printf -v line "%s\n%s" "$line" "$line2"
    fi
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
done
```

To do the same as the sed's `-i.bak`, you can use the bash version with something like:

```
for file in *.java; do
   cp -p "$file" "$file.bak"
   ./script.bash < "$file.bak" > "$file"
done
```

Comment: hello, i have try the sed command, all work fine but only for the first occurence, i have try to add g option to find all occurence but i think i miss something, thanks for you help ;)

Comment: @MançauxPierre-Alexandre, are you sure the matching `/**` lines contain only those 3 characters plus `\n` (no space, etc...), that the input file is in Unix format (only `\n` at the end of lines) ?

Comment: in fact you are right, it work for first occurence because the first javadoc is on the class and they are no space before `/**` but the javadoc for class methods contains indentation with one or more space before. So i can have space before `/**` so i just need to remove `^` at the beginning of the regexp, and all work fine ;)

Comment: Good. To match exactly zero or more spaces before `/**`, you could also have changed `^` with `^ *` (with a space between the `^` and the `*`).